# MySQL query column descending order when column has varchar+number

Tags: mysql, sql

Input

```
REST_API_6007
REST_API_6
REST_API_4006
REST_API_4000
REST_API_3000
REST_API_3
REST_API_2
REST_API_1
```

Expected output :

```
REST_API_6007
REST_API_4006
REST_API_4000
REST_API_3000
REST_API_6
REST_API_3
REST_API_2
REST_API_1
```

Comment: It's a good idea to be more specific. (e.g try to describe better what you want to do or add your code)

Comment: Please do not add lots of different RDBMS. Only tag the one that you are using.

Comment: Don't keep your own copy of a post, other people may have edited it, click on 'edit' to edit & don't overwrite if you have been told someone else has edited. You removed an edit improving format. (Please read the edit help.)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, use `SUBSTR` to split the string and then `ORDER BY` the string part and then the numeric part:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY SUBSTR(column_name, 1, 9) DESC,
         TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(column_name, 10)) DESC
```

Or using `INSTR` to find the last underscore:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY SUBSTR(column_name, 1, INSTR(column_name, '_', -1)) DESC,
         TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(column_name, INSTR(column_name, '_', -1) + 1)) DESC;
```

Or regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, '^(\D+)(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) DESC,
         TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, '^(\D+)(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2)) DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nZheGJEi)

In other RDBMS, use the same techniques with the appropriate functions for finding sub-strings and converting strings to numbers.

Comment: i am trying in mysql

Comment: can you please help the same query for mysql